# Calculating discrete PDF from discrete CDF in python

Tags: python, numpy, probability-density, cdf

If we have discrete cdf for quantiles like

```
quantiles = array([1.000e-04, 1.000e-03, 1.000e-02, 2.000e-02, 3.000e-02, 4.000e-02,
   5.000e-02, 6.000e-02, 7.000e-02, 8.000e-02, 9.000e-02, 1.000e-01,
   2.000e-01, 3.000e-01, 4.000e-01, 5.000e-01, 6.000e-01, 7.000e-01,
   8.000e-01, 9.000e-01, 9.100e-01, 9.200e-01, 9.300e-01, 9.400e-01,
   9.500e-01, 9.600e-01, 9.700e-01, 9.800e-01, 9.900e-01, 9.990e-01,
   9.999e-01])
```

Is it valid to create a reverse mapping linear interpolation ? That is from the cdf quantiles, we estimate the value of the random variable satifying cdf condition `p(x < a) = p_a`. Then we get uniformly distributed values from 0 to 1 and generate random variable in question (think of mapping from y to x axis on a cdf plot). Would the PDF from this be a good approximation ?

```
f = interp1d(quantiles, matching_discrete_cdf, kind='linear')
uni_rv = stats.uniform.rvs(loc=percentiles.min(), 
         scale=percentiles.max() - percentiles.min(), size=nof_items)
pdf = f(uni_rv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that when you write "pdf" you mean "sample" and not an actual [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function); and when you write "matching_discrete_cdf", you mean the "percent point function" (PPF) which is the inverse of CDF. The terminological confusion aside, the idea is sound: generating a sample for a custom distribution by transforming a uniform sample by the PPF is a standard approach.

The interpolation will distort the distribution a little, and so will the fact that the quantiles 1.000e-04 and 9.999e-01 of the original distribution will become the min and max of the generated numbers (the original distribution had some small chance of being outside these limits). But this should be acceptable, and is inevitable given the data you have. Maybe use the cubic interpolation instead of linear one?

On the chance that you actually want the PDF and not a sample -- the PDF is the derivative of the CDF. I would use cubic spline interpolation on the CDF values ([InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline)), and then take its [derivative](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivative.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivative).